# xelatex - how to change font size (resize)

Tags: equations, xetex, fontsize, resize

I am creating equation through code (C#) to png file.
How I can change a size of equation?
Because sometimes my equation is long and the image contains small characters and for short equations the image contains large characters.

My process contain 3 steps:

1. Generate PDF

Below my code:

```
\documentclass[6pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathrm{Arial}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{
{formula} 
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

2. PDFCROP

3.PDF TO PNG

Example how it is generated:
[image]

code:

1. generate pdf - command run in cmd:

-output-directory={outputDictionary} -jobname {_imageName} {expression}

2. pdf corp - command run in cmd:

-margin 3 {_imageName}.pdf {_imageName}-crop.pdf

3. Pdf to Png - command run in cmd:

-png {_imageName}-crop.pdf {_imageName}

Comment: article does not have `6pt` option. your tex code will always produce 10pt characters if sometimes you get long sometimes short you must be scaling while creating the image but you have not shown the code or any real example formulae

Comment: I added image with generated formula and code example  in main post.

Comment: you don't say what commands you use to do the conversion, only the arguments you use.. Don't show redacted inages of your real document, show the actual output from the test document so people can reproduce the problem